# Проверка столкновений в игре "Tron"

Tags: разработка-игр

Есть сложность в проверки коллизий в игре c++.Мной была выбрана проверка  матрицей.Суть заключалась в том,что при движении моего объекта я ставлю 1 или 2 в матрицу.Теперь я хочу сравнить ,что если мой объект находится в той же координате по матрице и она не пустая , то я выхожу из программы.Но почему-то игра сразу же падает,как только загружается.

```
void collision (float x,float y,Context &ctx){
    for (int i = 0;i<256;i++ ){
        for(int j = 0;j < 256;j++){
            if (matrix[int(x)][int(y)] != 0) {
                ExitApp(ctx);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: У Вас matrix какого типа? Если с плавающей запятой, то он не будет равен нулю.

Comment: Матрица int'ов .Видимо суть в том,что я ставлю еденичку в матрицу,а затем проверяюю ее,поэтому я падаю,не знаю как построить условие

Comment: Эээ... Следующий вопрос....  А зачем вам циклы,  если вы проверяете только один элемент?        А установки единицы в этом фрагмент нет,  так что ничего о ней сказать не могу